# a column of empty and filled circles

Tags: graphics

I wish to show 20 circles in a vertical rectangular whose `m` circles are filled. `n` circles for example colored by `green` and `m-n` colored by `red`. The radius of circles are the same and can be `r`. The circles are not filled are empty. How do I reach this aim? 
I wish to specify the position of green circles and red circles manually. For example: the first be green, the second be red, the third be green and the fourth, the remainder be empty. AND NOT Random.

[image]

Comment: You can do that with a combination of `Disk` and `Graphics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
colors = {Green, Red, Green, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[White, 17]};
r = 
  Table[Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .5], {m, 1}, {n, 20}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], Riffle[Reverse@colors, Flatten@r]},
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
 FrameTicks -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to specify your desired order in `colors`. I was doing something similar with `Rectangles`, so that's why I use them here instead of explicit circles (`RoundingRadius->0.5` of a `Rectangle[]` equals a circle).

Comment: Thank you so much, your approach is very near to what I was searching,

Comment: @Irreversible, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
GraphicsColumn[Table[Graphics[{RandomChoice[{Green, Red, White}],
     Disk[{i, 0}, 0.4], Black, Circle[{i, 0}, 0.4]}], {i, 20}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But I wish to specify the position of green circles and red circles manually. For example: the first be green, the second be red, the third be green and the fourth, the remainder be empty. AND NOT Random.

Comment: @Irreversible What have you tried and where did you get stuck? This answer shows the basics. You can just as easily pull the colour from another list indexed by `i`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I have exploited `GraphicsColumn[{Graphics[Disk[]], Graphics[Disk[]], Graphics[Disk[]]}, (which is in the help Mathematica)
  Frame -> All]`, But unfortunately I had to create twenty copies of the line for specifying the position of colored circles.